# MySql datetime format change

Tags: mysql, date, mysql-date

I have stored date in string format like 'Thu, 24 Dec 2020 07:54:35 GMT'.

Can someone please suggest how to convert this string into YYYY-MM-DD format using MySQL query.

Tried this function :

```
 str_to_date(dateTime, '%a %d %b %Y %T %x')
    
    DATE_FORMAT(dateTime, '%Y-%m-%d)
    
   DATE(dateTime)
```

Comment: I tried so many ways but didn't find the solution and then i post the question

Comment: updated my question but don't know how to set the placeholder for timezone.

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE(@date, '%a, %d %b %Y %k:%i:%s GMT')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just ignore stuff that comes at the end (assuming you're happy to store the time for the given time zone)...

E.g.

```
select str_to_date('Thu, 24 Dec 2020 07:54:35 GMT', '%a, %e %b %Y %T') dt;
```